# Connecting to Amazon SQS using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto3

I am trying to connect to a Amazon SQS via the python boto library.

```
import boto3
sqs= boto3.resource('sqs')
for queue in sqs.queues.all():
    print(queue.url)
```

I have stored my credentials on the ~/.aws/credentials  file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYY
region=us-west-2
```

But when I execute the code I get an error

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when
>   calling the ListQueues operation: Access to the resource
>   https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.

I tried connecting directly to the queue. 
    LCqueue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='myQueue')

But then it tells me there is no such queue. Even though I can see it on the AWS management console. Any ideas ?

I also get an error on my IAS managment console. where I cant list any users.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the previous version of Boto (2)

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure your user have `SQS` permission granted ?

Go to *IAM* services, select your user (the one you use from your CLI) and check the group/permission attached to your user.

If you don't have, you can search for `SQS` in the "Search IAM" box (top left)

[image]

Select "Attach entities to AmazonSQSReadOnlyAccess (or AmazonSQSFullAccess)" and attach the pre-defined policy on your user

Comment: Do I have to do it using AWS management console ? Because I cant see a Search IAM box on it ?

Comment: Ok  i found the search  IAM box, but I get no results when I type sqs on it

Comment: hum weird you should have match. I attached screenshot. It should be from the aws console - then IAM services

Comment: I get an error when I click on users. `User: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/yyy  is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/ `

Comment: ok so you need to contact your aws admin so he grants you the rights on your user

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers also have their usefulness, my problem ended up just being that I needed to explicitly pass `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` arguments to the boto3.client() call. (Having the [default] configuration in ~/.aws/credentials wasn't sufficient.)

```
import boto3
from django.conf import settings

sqs = boto3.client('sqs',
                   region_name=settings.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
                   aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                   aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

While I'm pulling from `settings` for these values, the values that are in `settings` are ultimately being pulled from env variables, i.e. **don't** just save your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to your settings file and commit to Git. They're sensitive data and you'd also want to be able to update them on the fly, rather than recommitting, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Why couldn't this be in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but if someone gets to SO first: this could be because of the region you're trying to connect to.

I could access SQS in us-east-1 via aws web console, however trying to retrieve the messages from the queue in us-east-1 resulted in Access Denied from a python client.

Thankfully, from the github discussion: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/188#issuecomment-258880267, I tried changing the region to the one where I was supposed to have permissions and I was able to receive messages from the queue created in that region.